# XSL list Reverse

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a list with songs that produced from a music application and I want to project the reverse list in a website. For example I have the list:

```
Deep Zone Vs Balthazar - Dj Take Me Away (In The Mix) (12:24:45)
Tom Boxer Feat Antonia - Morena (12:27:43)
Alexandra Stan - Lemonade (12:30:16)
Flo Rida feat. Timbaland - Elevator (12:33:43)
```

The XML file that creates the list is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Event status="happened">
    <Song title="Dj Take Me Away (In The Mix)">
        <Artist name="Deep Zone Vs Balthazar" ID="335712"></Artist>
        <Info StartTime="12:24:45" JazlerID="12619" PlayListerID="" />
    </Song>
    <Song title="Morena">
        <Artist name="Tom Boxer Feat Antonia" ID="335910"></Artist>
        <Info StartTime="12:27:43" JazlerID="13079" PlayListerID="" />
    </Song>
    <Song title="Lemonade">
        <Artist name="Alexandra Stan" ID="335773"></Artist>
        <Info StartTime="12:30:16" JazlerID="12693" PlayListerID="" />
    </Song>
    <Song title="Elevator">
        <Artist name="Flo Rida feat. Timbaland" ID="335818"></Artist>
        <Info StartTime="12:33:43" JazlerID="12837" PlayListerID="" />
    </Song>
</Event>
```

And the XSL file is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 

<xsl:template match="Event">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Artist">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Song">


<html>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li style="margin-bottom: -10px; margin-left: -30px; list-style: circle;">
      <xsl:for-each select="Artist">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
      - 
      <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>

      <span>
        (<xsl:for-each select="Info">
        <xsl:value-of select="@StartTime"/>
        </xsl:for-each>)
      </span><br />
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>
</html>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I reverse the list so I can have the last played song on top of the list and follow by the earlier songs played?

---

*I'm new to this community and despite the research I've made in the site, I didn't find a solution for the problem below.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Event">
    <html>
        <body>
            <ul>
                <xsl:for-each select="Song">
                    <xsl:sort select="position()" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                    <li>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Artist/@name"/>
                        <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
                        <xsl:text> (</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Info/@StartTime"/>
                        <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
                    </li>
                </xsl:for-each> 
            </ul>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

XSLT/XPath 3 (or even 2, don't remember) has a `reverse` function so doing `select="reverse(Artist)"` will suffice in that version.

Otherwise use e.g.

```
<xsl:for-each select="Artist">
  <xsl:sort select="position()" order="descending"/>
  ...
</xsl:for-each>
```

Based on your and further comments your original code using `for-each select="Artist"` doesn't seem to process and output a "list" of artists at all, so that way of course, if you process a single `Artist` element, neither `reverse` nor sorting in reverse `position()` order will change anything.

I suppose higher up you process the `Song` elements so use `<xsl:for-each select="reverse(Song)">` or `<xsl:apply-templates select="reverse(Song)"/>` in XSLT 3 or `<xsl:for-each select="Song"><xsl:sort select="position()" order="descending"/>...</xsl:for-each>` or `<xsl:apply-templates select="Song"><xsl:sort select="position()" order="descending"/></xsl:apply-templates>` in versions where `reverse` is not supported.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. My xsl version is 1.0 unfortunately and came from the version of the music application. I cannot upgrade it. Is there any solution for this version?

Comment: @DigiSol, the answer gives an alternative, no? If the `for-each select="Artist"` in your original code works and output things in document order, then simply add `<xsl:sort select="position()" order="descending"/>` to output in reverse order.

Comment: It should be `<xsl:for-each select="Song">`. With the given structure, `<xsl:for-each select="Artist">` will never return a list, from any context.

Comment: @Martin Honnen, it is not working with both of solutions

Comment: @michael.hor257k: it is not working with both of solutions

Comment: @DigiSol Please edit your question and show a complete, executable stylesheet along with the exact expected result (as code) - see [mcve].

Comment: @DigiSol, see the edit, perhaps it helps, otherwise show your complete code that produces the original output, the `for-each select="Artist"` you have shown seems meaningless for the input you have shown, that way my first suggestion to reverse the order there can't have any effect. But you haven't shown the right code that outputs the list of songs so sorry for trying to fix the wrong code.

Comment: I already edit the code